# Apache errorlog piping fail

Tags: apache-2.4, rsyslog, pipe

Trying to log to a central syslog server, either direct using Apache's ErrorLog to pipe to logger, or getting syslog to forward, but nothing is working and the errors are not making sense to me. I can get the Custom log to work, but not ErrorLog. Using Apache/2.4.7 on Ubuntu 14.04 with rsyslogd 7.4.4.

Config in my vhost (with and without space after logger options makes no difference):

```
LogLevel warn
ErrorLog  "|/usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/apache2/error.log | /usr/bin/logger -tapache_err -plocal1.error"
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/logger -p local4.warning -t apache" combined
```

and then getting this error:

```
/usr/bin/tee: invalid option -- 't'
```

Also tried (with and without double quotes):

```
ErrorLog "|syslog:local1"
```

But then got:

```
(2)No such file or directory: AH00089: Couldn't start ErrorLog process 'syslog:local1'.
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Even tried:

```
ErrorLog "| /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/apache2/error.log | nc -u -j xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 514"
```

But then tee is still complaining:

```
/usr/bin/tee: invalid option -- 'u'
```

Why on earth is `tee` picking up options after the second pipe and what can I do to stop that? I am a but stuck, Google isn't my friend, and any other advice is appreciated.

Comment: Regarding ErrorLog to syslog, with your attempt above in quotes and with "|" pipe, apache is wanting to write a file by that name. Instead, the directive should be just:

    ErrorLog syslog:local1

(no quotes, no pipes)

Answer (score 8):

The first pipe is code for Apache to fork a new command, but it's probably not forking a whole new shell, which would allow you to use a new pipe, but instead exec'ing the command, so everything is treated as a command argument, including the new pipe etc. You can likely go around it by wrapping it into a shell, using two methods, one is explicitly:

```
ErrorLog "|/bin/sh -c 'tee ... | logger ...'"
```

And the other is implicitly, using the prefix keyword `|$`:

```
ErrorLog "|$tee ... | logger ..."
```

The root cause is a change in Apache 2.4, cf. http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html:

*On Unix platforms, piped logging commands configured using either ErrorLog or CustomLog were invoked using /bin/sh -c in 2.2 and earlier. In 2.4 and later, piped logging commands are executed directly. To restore the old behaviour, see the piped logging documentation.*

Comment: Perfect, that worked like a charm! This has been doing my head in for a while because according to Apache's docs it should work direct. Thanks

Comment: The strange part here is that http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html#piped says it should be forking a shell by default.

Comment: I know - thats the part that did my head in, but for some reason it wasn't, and this is a default install of Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: This answer also solved [a similar problem](http://serverfault.com/questions/700708/how-to-set-the-correct-file-permissions-for-custom-logging-with-apache-2) for me. It should be accepted.

Comment: The right documentation for this Apache version is http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#piped

Answer (score 1):

Found this post while searching for a solution involving scrubbing log events from `ErrorLog` in Apache 2.2.31 which does not yet have `ErrorLogFormat`.
Here's the solution I came up with, and thought others would find it useful.

This strips referer from the `ErrorLog` using unbuffered `sed`:

```
ErrorLog "|/bin/sed -u \'s/,\ referer: .*//\' >> /var/log/httpd/error_log"
```

Strips the querystring from referer using inline unbuffered `perl`:

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/local/bin/perl -ne \'$|=1;while (<>){$output = $_; $output =~ s/(referer:\ .*)\?/$1/; print $output}\'>>/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

Call a perl script:

```
ErrorLog "|/usr/local/bin/perl /tmp/fuss.pl >> /var/log/httpd/error_log
```